# Digital/Analog voltage conversion and switching

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, voltage-divider, power-electronics, switching-regulator

What circuit topology should I use for digital high voltage (20v-30v) to low voltage (3.3v-5v) conversion (for MCU input) and vice-versa? I can think about the following topology:

1. Voltage divider based
2. Power MOSFET based switching with NMOS gate drive

Further to this question, what topology should I use for analog voltage and current input from high side (20-30v) to MCU side (3.3v-5v) for ADC input? I can think about the following topology:

1. Non-inverting Op-amp amplifier
2. Voltage controlled current amplifier

Reference: I wanted to integrate the solution into my existing embedded system and the particular product feature I am looking for can be referred from this link: http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?category=0&product_id=1012_2

Answer (score 1):

1. For digital signals - Voltage divider + zener
2. For analog signals - Inverting OpAmp (a non inverting Op amp cannot attenuate)
   You can then "correct" the inversion by firmware or by SW, or you could use a voltage divider followed by a unity gain non inverting op amp.

Comment: 1. This is for digital input, what topology for digital output from low side to high side.

Comment: 2. Analog - What about analog input current? Input side is having 0mA to 20mA current range.

Comment: For an analog input current you can make a current to voltage converter using an op amp

Comment: My circuit is supposed to switch faster and power efficient as well. I have a general understanding that voltage divider circuits always consume current and thus power dissipation happens.  Further, for logic level conversion, most modern circuit designs are made up MOSFET+NMOS topology. Where to consider MOSFET in switching and voltage conversion application?

Answer (score 1):

> What circuit topology should I use for digital high voltage (20v-30v) to low voltage (3.3v-5v) conversion (for MCU input) and vice-versa? I can think about the following topology: 1. Voltage divider based 2. Power MOSFET based switching with NMOS gate drive.

Voltage divider. It's very simple and requires no active components. If calibration is required a small trim-pot can be added. See Figure 1a.

For DAC output 0 - 30 V, a non-inverting opamp is required. See Figure 1b. Gain is \$ 1 + \frac{R_5}{R_6} \$. I have chosen supply voltages so that the opamp doesn't have to run rail to rail. You may decide otherwise.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmFcVr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> Further to this question, what topology should I use for analog voltage and current input from high side (20-30v) to MCU side (3.3v-5v) for ADC input? Input side is having 0mA to 20mA current range.

For this you need a current to voltage converter - a resistor. See Figure 1c.

Comment: My circuit is supposed to switch faster and power efficient as well. I have a general understanding that voltage divider circuits always consume current and thus power dissipation happens.  Further, for logic level conversion, most modern circuit designs are made up MOSFET+NMOS topology. Where to consider MOSFET in switching and voltage conversion application?

Comment: Faster than what? What power loss have you calculated for the potential divider suggested?

Comment: You are not doing logic level conversion. You specified analog.

Comment: This last comment is particularly for digital input/output question. Particularly I am looking for a solution according to this device which is using NMOSFET: http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?category=0&product_id=1012_2

Comment: Sorry, but that's a new question.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to copy a Phidget?

Comment: Since my questions were not clear, so provided the reference link. I am not trying to copy but particularly asking: "for logic level conversion, most modern circuit designs are made up MOSFET+NMOS topology. Where to consider MOSFET in switching and voltage conversion application?"